# Magazine's readership base diagram: "Distribution by job title" - would this be a good diagram title?

Tags: phrase-requests, translation

Below is a diagram (translated from Russian) that describes the distribution of a magazine in terms of who its subscribers are. I'm thinking of changing the title of the diagram to "distrubution by **job title**", because to my taste **functional status** is not very suitable for this context. Maybe I'm wrong, however. The original Russian title of the diagram is **Кадровый состав** (Cadre composition).

What could be other phrases suitable for this situation? **By job capacity**?

> [image]

Comment: *Job title* is the most usual form, and probably the most understandable.

Comment: "Job function", not necessarily title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Job title** is not *quite* correct. Your "job title" is what your employer chose to put on your contract, and is on your business card and email signature. "Job titles" are therefore industry (and even company) specific.

The subscribers to your magazine may or may not all be from the same industry, but there's still no guarantee of consistency of job title. What one company calls a "Marketing Director" another company might call a "Vice President - Marketing" and still another might simply call him a "Partner" (and it just so happens that his particular role is marketing).

So, I would suggest either **[Job function](http://work.chron.com/differences-between-job-function-job-title-15200.html)** or **[Job role](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107632/job-title-vs-job-role)**.

> Job function is the routine set of tasks or activities undertaken by a person in that position. An employee's title and function are often closely related, though not all job functions are clear based on title alone.

<sup>work.chron.com</sup>

> A "job role" is a description of what a person does. A "job title" is a convenient name for a role.

<sup>english.stackexchange.com</sup>